# Clave foranea vacia (sin datos) PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta con respecto a base de datos y formularios en PHP:

Yo tengo la siguiente **tabla usuarios**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`usuarios` (

`nombres` VARCHAR(30) NULL,

`apellidos` VARCHAR(30) NULL,

`dni` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,

`telefono` VARCHAR(15) NULL,

`direccion` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

`sexo` VARCHAR(10) NULL,

`sesion_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`cedula`),

INDEX `fk_usuarios_sesion_idx` (`sesion_id` ASC),

CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_sesion`

FOREIGN KEY (`sesion_id`)

REFERENCES `login`.`sesion` (`id`)

ON DELETE CASCADE

ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Y tengo la **tabla sesion**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`sesion` (

`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`correo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

`usuario` VARCHAR(10) NULL,

`password` VARCHAR(100) NULL,

`last_session` DATETIME NULL,

`activacion` INT NULL,

`token` VARCHAR(40) NULL,

`token_password` VARCHAR(100) NULL,

`password_request` INT(11) NULL,

`id_tipo` INT(11) NULL,

`estatus` INT(2) NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Ellas están relacionadas entre sí de 1 a 1. La clave principal de sesiones está como clave foranea en usuarios.

En PHP tengo un formulario para que los usuarios se registren en mi sistema. Todo se inserta normal en las tablas pero solo tengo un problema, porque si en la tabla sesions el ID es autoincrement porque siendo ella misma foránea en usuarios no se llena también?

En este momento he registrado ya a varios usuarios en mi sistema, y todo se inserta bien, pero la clave foranea siempre está vacía, no se asocia con el número que se asigna autoincrement en sesiones.

Para insertar lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
function registraUsuario($nombres, $apellidos, $cedula, $telefono, $direccion, $sexo){

            global $mysqli;

            $stmtr= $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombres, apellidos, cedula, telefono, direccion, sexo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmtr->bind_param('ssssss', $nombres, $apellidos, $cedula, $telefono, $direccion, $sexo);

                if ($stmtr->execute()){
                return true;
                } else {
                return 0;

            }   

            }


        function registraSesion($email, $usuario, $pass_hash, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario, $estatus){

            global $mysqli;

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO sesion (correo, usuario, password, activacion, token, id_tipo, estatus) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('sssisii', $email, $usuario, $pass_hash, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario, $estatus);


            if ($stmt->execute()){
                return $mysqli->insert_id;
                } else {
                return 0;   

            }   

        }
```

Adicional debo decir que tengo a la llave foranea como NULL porque si no la coloco NULL, simplemente los datos que registre para usuarios (nombres, apellidos, dni..) no se registran...pero estando NULL si se registra todo sin inconvenientes excepto la clave foranea.

Por favor, si pueden ayudarme con este problema que tengo, o si pueden decirme como puedo hacer o que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Es muy simple, que una clave sea foranea no indica que se autoinserte ella sola, tienes que insertarla tu en la query. Ademas si hay concurrencia de ejecucion deberias utilizar transacciones para evitar corrupcion de datos.

Comment: @Lithorell ya hice eso pero sigue sin aparecer algo en la columna sesion_id

Comment: Yo no veo que tu insert introduzca valor en session_id